# How to have a click anywhere hide a popover by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code which, when a button is clicked, shows a popover, which is working fine.  But it persists in showing.

I want to be able to click anywhere to hide this popover.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="popover-edit arrow_box">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

and this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".mobile-edit").on("click", function() {
  $(".popover-edit").toggleClass("animate");
return false;    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Im understanding correctly...

```
$(document).ready (function(){

    $('body').on('click', function(){
        $(".popover-edit").css('display','none');
    });
)};
```

Whenever the body is clicked on, the `.popover-edit` element will no longer display

Comment: tanks @AdamJeffers your code is not working where i put this code

Comment: Check my revisions mate

Comment: not working  but i find this solution: <script type="text/javascript">
$(".mobile-edit").on("click", function() {
    
  $(".popover-edit").toggleClass("animate").show();;
  
  $('body').on('click', function(){
    $(".popover-edit").css("display","none"); 
});
return false;    
});


</script> 
this code woks fine but there is a small problem when click anywhere the popover hide but when i want to click button again to show popover i try to click two times to show popover again what is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93186/discussion-between-adamjeffers-and-iklas).